# Code crash on iPhone Simulator but works on actual iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, rss, parsing, flickr, simulator

This is an extremely weird problem: wondering if anybody has experienced this before. My code, an RSS parser of Flickr photos (RSS feed), works perfectly on an actual device, but allocates a ton of memory and freezes up my entire computer when run on the simulator.

I know usually it's the other way round for people, but this is acting weird. Any clue why? In the app, I have 2 other places using the exact same code, but used to parse youtube feeds and general rss feeds, and they work fine, but not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Flickr code.  I've had this happen before; when you run an app in the Simulator, it's actually compiled for an Intel chip, not ARM like on an iPhone.  Basically, your code is being translated into Intel assembly incorrectly.